# Splunk: search a string, if found only then look for another log with same request-id

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want to find a string (driving factor) and if found, only then look for another string with same x-request-id and extract some details out of it.

```
x-request-id=12345 "InterestingField=7850373" [this one is subset of very specific request]
x-request-id=12345 "veryCommonField=56789" [this one is a superSet of all kind of requests]
```

What I've tried:

```
index=myindex "InterestingField" OR "veryCommonField"
| transition x-request-id
```

But problem with above is this query join all those request as well which has only veryCommonField in it.
I want to avoid join as they are pretty low in performance.

What I need:
list InterestingField, veryCommonField

Example:
Below represents beginning of all kind of request. We get thousands of such request in a day.

```
index=myIndex xrid=12345 "Request received for this. field1: 123 field2: test"
```

Out of all above request below category falls under 100.

```
index=myIndex xrid=12345 "I belong to blahBlah category. field3: 67583, field4: testing"
```

I don't want to search in a super-set of 1000k+ but only in matching 100 requests. Because with increased time span, this search query will take very long.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your use-case, the following may be helpful.

Using stats

```
index=myindex "InterestingField" OR "veryCommonField" | stats values(InterestingField), values(veryCommonField) by x-request-id
```

Using subsearch

```
index=myindex [ index=myindex InterestingField=* | fields x-request-id | format  ]
```

Depending on the number of results that match `InterestingField`, you can also use `map`, https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.3/SearchReference/Map

```
index=myindex InterestingField="*" | map maxsearches=0 "search index=myindex x-request-id=$x-request-id$ | stats values(InterestingField), values(veryCommonField) by x-request-id"
```

If you provide more thorough example events, we can assist you further.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Subsearch is best suited to my requirement here. But how do i extract field using rex in inner search and table them in my final search. ```index=myindex "_my_search_string_"
| rex "before(?<myField1>.*).*"
    [ index=myindex "_my_another_space separated string"
    | rex "before(?<myField2>.*).*"
    | table myfield
    | fields x-request-id 
    | format ]
| table myField1, myField2```